Previsualizar imagen con javascript falla
estoy intentando que mi input file ejecute una funcion de js al momento de cambiar,y que se previsualice la imagen en un img que tengo.
Todo iba bien, me leia bien el id del input y el id de la imagen lo calculaba correctamente con el replace, sin embargo, al momento de ejecutar el codigo que hace eso de ver la imagen algo falla y no logro descifrar por que.
Anteriormente habia usado el mismo codigo para un form individual, pero esta vez estoy haciendo un crud y quiero lograr que al cambiar la imagen de una fila se logre ver.
html input file e img
<img src = './img/curriculum/" . $foto_aux . "' class = 'fotos_crud_exis' width = '100px' id= 'foto" . $contador . "' name = 'foto" . $contador . "'>
<input type='file' name='foto_e" . $contador . "' id='foto_e" . $contador . "' class='filecrud' onchange = 'photodinamica(this.id)'>

funcion js
function photodinamica(input_id) {
    id_input_fila = input_id;
    string_img = id_input_fila.replace("foto_e", "foto");
    console.log(id_input_fila);
    console.log(string_img);
    const defaultfile = './img/curriculum/emple.png';
    const file = document.getElementById(id_input_fila);
    const img = document.getElementById(string_img);
    file.addEventListener('change', e => {
        if (e.target.files[0]) {
            const reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function (e) {
                img.src = e.target.result;
            }
            reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0]);

        } else {
            img.src = defaultfile;
        }
    });

}

Aun no dimino js, por favor ayudenme :(. Gracias

<img src = './img/curriculum/" . $foto_aux . "' class = 'fotos_crud_exis' width = '100px' id= 'foto" . $contador . "' name = 'foto" . $contador . "'>
<input type='file' name='foto_e" . $contador . "' id='foto_e" . $contador . "' class='filecrud' onchange = 'photodinamica(this.id)'>

Tienes que usar el .file[0] para seleccionar el archivo del input y luego new FileReader; te dejo aquí el codigo JS:
function photodinamica(input_id) {
    id_input_fila = input_id;
    string_img = id_input_fila.replace("foto_e", "foto");

    const img = document.getElementById(string_img);
    const file = document.getElementById(id_input_fila).files[0];
    const reader = new FileReader();

    reader.addEventListener(
        "load",
        function () {
        // convierte la imagen a una cadena en base64
        img.src = reader.result;
        },
        false,
    );

    if (file) {
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }
} 


Muchas gracias por la solucion!

No hay de que, pero lo que te decía el compañero tiene razón, mejor que pasar el this.id es pasar todo el elemento this, o buscar otra opción para llamar al input y a la img.  ah! y si te fijas, no uso el evento onchange dentro de la función que has hecho llamada desde onchange, uso el evento load

tu problema es el siguiente
<input type='file' name='foto_e" . $contador . "' id='foto_e" . $contador . "' class='filecrud' onchange = 'photodinamica(this.id)'>

tu aqui agregas un evento onchange
onchange = 'photodinamica(this.id)'

el primer error es que pasas el id(this.id) en lugar de lugar de pasar directamente el input(this) pero eso solo es cuestión optimización
file.addEventListener('change', e => {
        if (e.target.files[0]) {
            const reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function (e) {
                img.src = e.target.result;
            }
            reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0]);

        } else {
            img.src = defaultfile;
        }
    });

el problema mas importante en el funcionamiento en cuando agrega un evento onchange dentro del evento onchange,
no si error pero debes saber que los eventos onchange no se borran solos si creas un ciclo donde agregas y agregas mas y mas...
si tu quiere por ejemplo cambiar una imagen con su vista previa cada vez que se seleciona una nueva imagen lo puedes hacer usando solo el onchange
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Subir y Mostrar Imagen</title>
    <style>
        .fotos_crud_exis {
            width: 100px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Selecciona una imagen</h2>

    <!-- Primer input e imagen con IDs dinámicos -->
    <input type="file" id="foto_input.1" _contador="1" accept="image/*" onchange="mostrarImagen(this)">
    <br><br>
    <img id="foto_mostrar.1" _contador="1" class="fotos_crud_exis" src="" alt="Imagen seleccionada" style="display:none;">

    <!-- Segundo input e imagen con IDs dinámicos -->
    <input type="file" id="foto_input.2" _contador="2" accept="image/*" onchange="mostrarImagen(this)">
    <br><br>
    <img id="foto_mostrar.2" _contador="2" class="fotos_crud_exis" src="" alt="Imagen seleccionada" style="display:none;">

    <script>
        // Función para mostrar la imagen seleccionada
        function mostrarImagen(input) {
            const contador = input.getAttribute('_contador'); // Obtener el valor de _contador del input
            const archivo = input.files[0]; // Obtener el archivo seleccionado

            if (archivo) {
                const lector = new FileReader();
                lector.onload = function(e) {
                    // Buscar la imagen correspondiente usando el ID dinámico "foto_mostrar.{contador}"
                    const imagen = document.getElementById('foto_mostrar.' + contador);
                    imagen.src = e.target.result; // Asignar la imagen cargada
                    imagen.style.display = 'block'; // Mostrar la imagen
                }
                lector.readAsDataURL(archivo); // Leer el archivo como URL
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>


Muchisimas gracias, he logrado lo que queria, te lo agradezco mucho de verdad!

me alegra que te ayudara, lo acabo de actualizar agregando dos casos de uso e id personalizados para no tener conflictos

vale, gracias, hice algo similar a mi manera con el id dinamico, sin duda la explicacion me ha servido bastante y me servira para otro caso que tengo. Muchas gracias de nuevo
